# Error: no match for 'operator!='

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

```
void super::findTarget(list<int>Dlist,list<super>::iterator t){

while(t != Dlist.end()){
 double mypos[3];
 double target[3];
 double fpos[3];
 double speed;
 double range;
 double a, b, c, D;

 mypos[0]=this->x;
 mypos[1]=this->y;
 mypos[2]=this->z;
 range = this->range;

 target[0]=t->x;
 target[1]=t->y;
 target[2]=t->z;

 a = target[0]-mypos[0];
 b = target[1]-mypos[1];
 c = target[2]-mypos[2];

 D = sqrt( pow(a,2.0)+pow(b,2.0)+pow(c,2.0));
 Dlist.push_back(D);
   };
};
```

On the 2nd line, `while (t != Dlist.end(){`, I'm getting the following error:

> C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\project\super.cpp|369|error: no match for 'operator!=' in 't != Dlist.std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::end >()'|

Am I just not allowed to do this inside of a function or am I missing something?

Comment: The operator `!=` is not implemented for the class of these objects. Eventually there is a function to do what you want ... or you have to code one.

Answer (score 4):

A `list<int>` and `list<super>` are two different `list`.  You cannot compare an iterator from one to an iterator from the other.

Answer (score 1):

I think you shouldn't compare a `list<int>::iterator` and a `list<super>::iterator`. There is no != operator that takes those two different types as arguments.

Comment: indeed, thank you. ive found another way to loop. – user3290184 just now   edit